# How to automatically shutdown PC when print spool empty?

Tags: printing, windows-11, shutdown, print-spooler

When I print many documents with PC, then spool PC needs on. If spool PC is off, then stop printing whenever documents are waiting on that PC.

By the way, I want to need automatically shutdown the spool PC when spool is empty. That means no more documents are waiting printer.

I think go to `event viewer > applications and services > Microsoft > Windows > PrintService > Operational` and  find such as 'request jobs are finished' log, and connect "Job Scheduler" to shutdown when 'request jobs are finished' log is appear will help me. But, Operational logs are only show the one document's job, not whole jobs.

How can I see log if print spool is empty? or How can I shutdown when print spool is empty? using PC's are windows 11.

Thank you.

Comment: SU isn't a script-writing service. Have a look at writing a PowerShell script to poll the spooler queue every x minutes in a loop, and then call the shutdown command when the queue is empty. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/printmanagement/get-printjob?view=windowsserver2022-ps & https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/stop-computer?view=powershell-7.3

Comment: @spikey_richie Thank you, this is really helpful link! I try later because I need test to make power shell script while printing. And I have one more question. what is SU that you mentioned?

Comment: SU is short for Super User; this sub-stack.

Comment: @spikey_richie Thank you! I didn't think about power shell script. Now, I make script and use very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make powershell script to do that work.

`Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PrintJob`
will be check your print spool.

please see @spikey_richie comment to see reference.